# Javascript Switch Case Not Working in socialengine

Tags: javascript, mootools, socialengine

I am feeling a bit embarrassed to ask this silly question but somehow the following code is not working. The values (bed,room,floor) are fetched right but switch case not working.But the same snippet of switch case code works well in jsfiddle.I m sure I m missing something silly.I m using this in socialengine with mootools enabled

I also want to know how to get an element which has id=roomtype and which is inside a div whose `class=form-elements` but `id=roomtype` is not direct child of div `class=form-elements`.
I can get it by `$$('.form-elements #roomtype').get('value')` but this refers all elements with #roomtype, this  `$('.form-elements #roomtype').get('value')` doesnt work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var updatePrice=function()
{

 var room= $$('.form-elements #roomtype').get('value')  ;

// alert (room) gets AirCon or Dorm
var price;

switch (room)
  {
  case "AirCon":
    price="10000"; alert("AirCon");
    break;
  case 'Dorm':
    price="5000"; alert("Dorm");
    break;
  default:
    price="00";
  }


}

 en4.core.runonce.add(updatePrice);// this add this function to DOM Ready
    </script>
```

Comment: "id" values must be unique. If you re-use an "id" for more than one element on a single page, things won't work properly.

Comment: Can you show the jsiffle on which it's working.

Comment: id is unique, the reason I used $$() is in my second question.I cant get that SINGLE element with $('.form-elements #roomtype').get('value'). The element is one of the childs(#roomtype) of a div element (.form-elements)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zWq6N/ since I m getting the var "room" well, the promlem maybe elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### #1

ID's **must** be unique.

In MooTools you can do `$('roomtype')` to get the element with the ID `roomtype`.

You can also use `document.id('roomtype')` or even `$$('#roomtype')`.
Since ID's must be unique it's irrelevant the parent of that element, because there is only one.

#### #2

Note that `$` and `$$` are different [**element methods in mootools**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element). `$$` takes a CSS selector and returns a collection/array.

```
$$('#roomtype').get('value'); // returns ['the value']
$('roomtype').get('value'); // return 'the value'
```

#### #3

The other problem I see is that you define the price inside the scope of `updatePrice()` function, so doing `price = 5000` inside the switch will not leave the function's scope anyway. You might want to define the var price outside the function, or make the function return that value lie this:

```
    // ...
    switch (room) {
        case "AirCon":
            price = "10000";
            alert("AirCon");
            break;
        case 'Dorm':
            price = "5000";
            alert("Dorm");
            break;
        default:
            price = "00";
    }
    return price; // here
}
```

If you update your fiddle with HTML it will be easier to help you more.

<sub>P.s: You are always welcome to ask questions. No need to feel embarrassed.</sub>

Comment: Thank u a lot. Actually I just wanted to know why $('.form-elements  #roomtype') doesnt refer to that single unique element whereas $$() does.And my problem is that the switch case is never reached,leave out the price variable.Even if(room=="Dorm") alert("D"); doesnt work.Here, variable room is getting data from a html select element which triggers onchange=updatePrice(); The event is triggerd well as I get any alert() in that function and values are also fetched, alert(room) shows well.Its really frustrating ...

Comment: @Tanvir, updated my answer. If this does not solve your problem, please add the code for `en4.core.runonce.add()`

Comment: pls check http://jsfiddle.net/zWq6N/2/ , having problem there but in my script event is triggered well.I must say the whole thing is made with zend framwork, so jsfiddle html is just the output of my code

Comment: @Tanvir, if you use just one `$` then don't use the `#`. Its _the same_ as `document.getElementById()`. Check here: __http://jsfiddle.net/zWq6N/3/__

Comment: The event is triggered only once at on DomReady but then never, wud u pls check that. Upon selecting each option an alert shud be made in each case.

Comment: Accepting ur answer for the kind effort. But the main problem still continues , Pls help, check ur jsfiddle again.

Comment: @Tanvir, that was just because jsFiddle loads the javascript insode a domready function, so it was out of scope. Sorry I missed that first. Here: __http://jsfiddle.net/hjc2c/__

Comment: Ohh,I thought after DomReady is loaded you can access all HTML Elements but not images, then why not inside Domready function.Actually I wanted to get seledted Value from a html select  upon triggered by another select.I was not getting the string value with room=$('roomtype').getSelected().get("value").After spending a long hour, finally I had to cast that value to string and VOILA!.I still wanna know Why that is so.room=String( $('roomtype').getSelected().get("value") ) did the trick. here check the jsfiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/zWq6N/6/  BTW, thank u sooo much for the help

Comment: @Tanvir, the thing is that getSelected returns a array do the result is `["NonAir"]`. Check __[link here](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:getSelected)__ But in fact you can just get the value from the select using `room = $('room').get("value");`. No need to `getSelected()`. Check __[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zWq6N/7/)__

Comment: Ohh I see that now.Thank u.Btw May I ask another question out of context here.       switch (building) {
            case "a": 
                If(room=="AirCon" && bed=="2"){ price=4000 } 
    else If(room=="NonAir" && bed=="1") { price=2500}
    else If(room=="Dorm" && bed=="1") {price=1000} } Why such condition shows error. U dont have to answer, id u dont want..lol

Comment: Ufff..it happens when u start coding after a long time...sigh!! Thank u a lot bro..